# Load HTML Template for use with knockout component via Browserify

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, browserify

I'm using browserify and knockout and am trying to load html files for knockout component templates.  I have browserify successfully loading javascript files, but I'm unclear on how to get it to load html files.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
(function() {
  var ko = require('./lib/knockout/dist/knockout.js');
  var authenticationViewModel = require('./viewmodels/authentication.js');
  var authenticationView = require('./views/authentication.html');

  ko.components.register('authentication', {
    template: authenticationView,
    viewModel: authenticationViewModel
  });
})();
```

But the template is obviously not loading. Can someone please explain to me how this is to be accomplished?

This is what I have in my gulpfile.js to get browserify to work with .js files:

```
  gulp.task('browserify', function () {
    var browserified = transform(function(filename) {
      var b = browserify(filename);
      return b.bundle();
    });

    return gulp.src([paths.appJs])
      .pipe(browserified)
      .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.public));
  });
```

I'm looking into the html-browserify plugin: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-browserify

The example they are using looks like this:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
  gulp.src('js/app.js')
    .pipe(browserify({
      insertGlobals: true,
      transform: html
    }))
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'));
});
```

But I'm unclear on how to reconcile this example with my current code that is already working.

Comment: require is for code, you want ajax for markup.

Comment: @dandavis - that would be an option, but I would prefer not to have to make tons of individual ajax calls to pull down the html templates of each and ever component I create.  There could be hundreds by the end of this project.  There has to be a way to bring them into scope with browserify.  Something that would potentially stringify the html and have the require module return back the html string.

Comment: if you can populate the require cache yourself, you could grab a zip file of templates at load to avoid many round-trips, or just grab from the zip as needed.

Comment: I have absolutely no experience using browserify, but I have used requirejs quite a lot. In requirejs you can load the HTML using the `text` plugin, by changing the load string to `'text!./views/authentication.html'`. Also, I suggest looking at the samples in the knockout documentation regarding loading components asynchronously (you can find it at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html), where you can find a sample of achieving what you want. Browserify also has some plugin functionality, so I guess it should be possible to get the same functionality in browserify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding and using partialify.  It works perfectly for inporting html files as dependencies.

```
  //Gulp Plugins
  var gulp = require('gulp');
  var browserify = require('browserify');
  var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
  var partialify = require('partialify');

  //Browserify
  gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    return browserify()
      .add(paths.browserifyEntry)
      .bundle()
      .pipe(source('main.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.public));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

[brfs](https://github.com/substack/brfs) should be one option.

In one of my own apps I use gulp to read some template files, combine them into an object, and write a JSON file that I load in my (browserified) app.